# Force Close With Viewpager

Tags: android

I'm developing an application retrieves the images from the server and store it in the sdcard.
I store the paths of the images in a local database, then i use them while using the viewpager to display them.
When there are only two images, everything works fine, but when there are more than two images , the app stops, and it happens while sliding between images. When i slide more than two times  , the app stops immediately.

```
class RequestLoadingMeals extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, Void> {
     protected void onPreExecute(){
          super.onPreExecute();
          PD = new ProgressDialog(Meals.this);
          PD.setMessage("Loading Meals, Please wait...");
          PD.setIndeterminate(false);
          PD.setCancelable(true);
          PD.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
          PD.show();
     }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        myDatabaseHandler.openToRead();
        Cursor meals_cursor = myDatabaseHandler.queueSomeMeals(rest_name);
        if (meals_cursor.moveToFirst())
          {
             do 
             {
                 try{
                 images.add(meals_cursor.getString(meals_cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHandler.KEY_MEAL_IMAGE_PATH)));
                 } catch (Exception h){ 
                 }
             }while (meals_cursor.moveToNext());
          }
        myDatabaseHandler.close();
        return null;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(final Void x) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(Meals.this, images);
        ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.mypager);
        myPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        myPager.setCurrentItem(0);
        PD.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Here is the viewpager class

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

 Activity activity;
 ArrayList<String> imageArray = new ArrayList<String>();


 public ViewPagerAdapter(Activity act, ArrayList<String> images) {
      imageArray = images;
      activity = act;
     }
 public int getCount() {
  return imageArray.size();
 }

 public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, int position) {
  ImageView view = new ImageView(activity);
  view.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams());
  view.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
  String path = imageArray.get(position);
  Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
  view.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
  ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);
  return view;
 }
 @Override
 public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
  return arg0 == ((View) arg1);
 }

 @Override
 public Parcelable saveState() {
  return null;
 }

}
```

Logcat:

```
12-02 12:46:38.956: E/AndroidRuntime(431): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-02 12:46:38.956: E/AndroidRuntime(431):java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException:Required method destroyItem was not overridden
12-02 12:46:38.956: E/AndroidRuntime(431):  at android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter.destroyItem(PagerAdapter.java:192)
12-02 12:46:38.956: E/AndroidRuntime(431):  at android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter.destroyItem(PagerAdapter.java:124)
12-02 12:46:38.956: E/AndroidRuntime(431):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1036)
12-02 12:46:38.956: E/AndroidRuntime(431):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
12-02 12:46:38.956: E/AndroidRuntime(431):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$3.run(ViewPager.java:244)
12-02 12:46:38.956: E/AndroidRuntime(431):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
12-02 12:46:38.956: E/AndroidRuntime(431):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-02 12:46:38.956: E/AndroidRuntime(431):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-02 12:46:38.956: E/AndroidRuntime(431):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
12-02 12:46:38.956: E/AndroidRuntime(431):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-02 12:46:38.956: E/AndroidRuntime(431):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-02 12:46:38.956: E/AndroidRuntime(431):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
12-02 12:46:38.956: E/AndroidRuntime(431):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
12-02 12:46:38.956: E/AndroidRuntime(431):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: logcat please ! bw it looks like you are running out of memory with more bitmaps. In that case you should use a good image loader library for loading images

Comment: I'm testing the app on my mobile because emulator give me an error while trying to store images on sdcard, so i can't post the logcat.
But i think it is not a problem of out of memory, i tried with two images, and it works good, and when i try with 3 images, it doesn't work, when i slide to the third image, the app stops after loading it, and i tried to slide only to the second image and back again to the first image , the problem also happened.

Comment: Did you assign sd card memory to your emulator ? Edit your emulator or create a new one and assign some memory to the sd card. it should work. That way you will get to see the logcat and it would be a lot easier to debug

Comment: I added the logcat , you can check now.

Comment: already answered by @M-WaJeEh below. Hope it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this in your `ViewPagerAdapter`:

```
@Override
public void destroyItem(View collection, int position, Object view) {
     ((ViewPager) collection).removeView((View) view);
}
```

and may I suggest not to do heavy long running tasks in `instantiateItem`. This is bad idea to decode images on UI thread.

Comment: Thank you, it works now.
But tell me what can i do to avoid heavy long running tasks in instantiateItem.
I think about decoding images in background using asynctask, and store these bitmaps in an Arraylist of Bitmaps, and display them in postExecute, What is your opinion ?

Comment: well if you will keep storing them in `ArrayList` you will eventually end up with out of memory error. I strongly suggest you to use Picasso http://square.github.io/picasso/  and then it will do all the work for you (memory caching, sdcard caching) etc

Comment: all you will need is this type of single line `Picasso.with(context).load(new File("/images/oprah_bees.gif")).into(imageView);` in `instantiateItem()`.